# Calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the problem, that my javascript function isn´t when I press the button:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">   
(function ($) {
    $.fn.addToList = function (opts) {
        var input = $(this);
        opts.button.click(function () {
            opts.list.append("<li>" + input.val() + "</li>");
        });
    };
}(window.jQuery));

$("#zutat").addToList({
    button: $("#btn"),
    list: $("#list")
});
</script>
```

and

```
<input type="text" id="zutat" name="zutat"></input>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click">
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

How do I call this javascript function? What is my problem?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mKtn2/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `script` tag is before the `#zutat"` stuff, then you are trying to manipulate on `#zutat` when the DOM elements are not ready yet. In this case, When the jQuery selector is being executed, it will not match the elements, since they are not available yet.

To fix it, you should wrap your codes by the `$(document).ready` function or put it at the bottom of `body` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">   
 (function($) {

  $.fn.addToList = function(opts) {
    var input = $(this);
    opts.button.click(function() {
      opts.list.append("<li>" + input.val() + "</li>");
    });
  };



  $(document).ready(function() { // <<<<<<< execute after document ready.
    $("#zutat").addToList({
      button: $("#btn"),
      list: $("#list")
    });
  });

})(window.jQuery);

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should move the parenthesis this way

```
})(window.jQuery);
```

In Firefox (I am using Firebug to test this) if you do this

```
function(){ alert("GONG"); }();
```

It gives you an error but if you wrap the function with parenthesis

```
(function(){ alert("GONG"); })();
```

The anonymous function will be executed.

You should also wrap the call to the dom elements in a `$(document).ready();` call as showed in qiao's answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add `<li>`s to a `<ul>` when you click a button, you are going about it in a very round about way.  you don't need to extend jquery or object prototype to do that.

try the following

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  var val = $("zutat").val();
  $("#list").append($("<li>" + val + "</li>"));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Normally the click event is handled like this

```
$('#btn').on("click",function(){
        // code
});
```

I don't know what your code does exactly but not that what you want.

Comment: `.click`, `.bind`, `.delegate`, `.live` etc already use `.on`. There is nothing wrong about using them (except `.live` of course).

Comment: your comment has nothing to do with my answer ? Be sure to read before you downvote

Comment: Your answer implies that the OP should use `.on`, no?

Comment: nope not really it recommends. and I don't get the your comment because I didn't imply him not to use click,bind,delegate,live...